# Linux distribution for a new user

Tags: distribution-choice

I am a Windows user, and I would like to try Linux.
I only have heard about Ubuntu, but I see even Ubuntu have many "sub-choices".
Which distribution would be the best for me.

Comment: Typically, the answer to these questions is "Try one and see." If you don't like it, move onto another one. *nix distros are deeply rooted in preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally use Linux mint, usually with the Mate desktop. Though cinnamon is just as good! A lot of people would probably suggest it as a beginners one too, as it is so user friendly and not too dissimilar to windows in how it looks and feels.
But choosing Linux is like choosing a car. There's so many out there with similarities and differences, the only real way of finding the right one for you is to test drive the ones you think you might like.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like `centos` but like aspman says, its like choosing a car.  Answer this question, "Why do you want try Linux?".  If you want to learn about Linux systems administration they try Debian distro and they try a Redhat distro.  If you want to learn about shell scripting maybe you could get away with installing Cygwin on you Window system.

Comment: Oh, man, you will know almost nothing after a year of using Debian. Let's get a Gentoo or BSD. It will teach you how to administrate a Unix.

Comment: I vote for arch. LFS (and gentoo) is probably best if you have the time and energy to delve deep, but arch will also force you to understand what you are doing, with better handholding and much better community support (the arch wiki pages are among the best there are out there)

Comment: @enedil Good point. Heck why not Mac OS?